# Implementation of Edge-enhancing diffusion(EED) with Diffusion tensor

Tags: python, image-processing, tensor, vision, pde

I am currently reading [Joachim Weickert:Anisotropic Diffusion in Image Processing](https://www.mia.uni-saarland.de/weickert/book.html) . There said Perona--Malik filter isn't anisotropic as it didn't use structure tensor. I can implement Perona--Malik but I am having trouble to implementing this edge enhancing diffusion filter. Can anyone help me with implementation or give me the explanation how the tensor is working there?

[image]

Comment: Here is an implementation in C++ of Weickert's Coherence Enhancing Diffusion: https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/1918cbcb89feac292689d02ecc2ab99326771851/src/nonlinear/anisotropic_diffusion.cpp#L236

Comment: Thanks..Do u have any implementaion on Weickert's Edge Enhancing Diffusion?

Comment: I'm a little hazy at the moment as to the difference between the two, but I can't imagine it's a lot of work to implement the one given the other, they should be fairly similar.